# Connecting a SQL Server Express 2008 R2 database to Visual Studio 2017 without upgrading it

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, windows-xp, compatibility, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am looking for a way to get a form application that I currently have designed in Visual Studio 2017 to run on Windows XP.

To do this (and as far as my limited knowledge allows me to understand), the program must use the .NET Framework 4 and a SQL Server Express 2008 R2 database (both compatible with Windows XP Service Pack 3). If this is not the case please correct me.

The problem is that, of the two versions I have of the database (one in SQL Server Express 2014 version and the other in SQL Server Express 2008 R2), only the first one is accepted when added as DataSource. The second one needs to be upgraded to a newer version, but of course that would mean, or so I understand, that it would no longer be a compatible database with Windows XP as it would reach a higher version than it can tolerate.

I would like to ask for help or guidance.

Comment: Why do you want/need to use technologies that have been *completely* unsupported for many years?

Comment: You could say it is part of an exercise to learn about compatibility.

Comment: I think you are going to be mostly on your own. Noone is supporting these anymore, and few people are going to be able to help. [so] only really kicked off in 2009, when XP use was already mostly declined. SQL2008R2 should have better compatibility, but you haven't show exactly what you tried that got an error. I need not reiterate that these are so out of date as to be effectively enormous security holes. But SQL Server runs as a server, therefore you can put it on any machine, and use a more modern version.

Comment: Windows XP ran out of support around **~9 years** ago; this isn't an exercise in compatibility it's an exercise is creating security vulnerabilities... If you want to work with compatibility, you'll best of trying to work out how to have old software run on newer hardware.